# Retiring permissions on Profiles and Lightning component visibility

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, profile, permission-sets

Salesforce is removing some permissions from Profiles (like object/field permissions) for Spring '26 release. Something interesting I found was this [known issue with no workaround](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001HliKQAS).

> Users without View Setup and Configuration don't see Lightning components whose visibility depends on a custom permission even if this has been enabled for the user via profile or permission set(s).

If we have to use Profiles to give visibility access to lightning components, wouldn't removing object/field permissions from Profiles completely break all our visibility criteria when this new release is live? How do we make visibility criteria based on custom permissions after this is live?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The KI is listed as fixed...?